# How do you template an IF statement to avoid an error if an image is not assigned

Tags: templating

Here is my templating...

```
      {% if entry.programImage %}
        <img src="{{ entry.programImage.one().getUrl() }}" alt=""/>
      {% endif %}
```

The field `programImage` is NOT required.

The image does display for entries that have it.
It throws an ERROR for those that do not.

The ERROR message is as follows.

```
Impossible to invoke a method ("getUrl") on a null variable.
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close...

```
{% set programImage = entry.programImage.one() %}
{% if programImage %}
    <img src="{{ programImage.getUrl() }}" alt=""/>
{% endif %}
```

You get the the asset model (or null), then check if you actually have it, then finally use it.

It's essentially the same in Craft 2.

Comment: I want this to work.  But, still not joy.   It still reads `impossible to invoke a method on a null variable.`. What I don't understand is that the `imageCaption` field is blank and this templating approach given in the Mijingo Craft3 course works for the `imageCaption` but does not translate to my attempt to apply it to `programImage`.  ``  {% if entry.programImageCaption %}
            <p class="caption">
                <small>{{ entry.programImageCaption }}</small>
            </p>
            {% endif %}``

Comment: I missed on thing.  I kept `entry.programImage` in the `if` statement.  I removed it, and it works. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

I talk about this type of "defensive coding" extensively in the [Handling Errors Gracefully in Craft CMS](https://nystudio107.com/blog/handling-errors-gracefully-in-craft-cms) article, if it helps.

The TL;DR is that the null coalescing operator is your friend:

`{% set image = entry.someImage.first() ?? someGlobal.defaultImage.first() ?? null %}
{% if image and image.kind == "image" %}
    <img src="{{ image.getUrl() }}" />
{% endif %}`

Answer (score 1):

`entry.programImage` does not contain the image. It is a prepared query to fetch the database row and populate the model. In order to gain the model/the asset you have to do `entry.programImage.one()` which will return the element or null.

```
{% if entry.programImage.one() %}
   ...
{% endif %}
```

If you want to make sure to check if the field is even in the layout you have to do

```
{% if entry.programImage is defined and entry.programImage is not empty %}
    {% set asset = entry.programImage.one %}
    {% if asset is not null %}
       You have an image
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: So, my initial construct was based on replicating the approach that works for the image caption.  This is the approach given in the Mijingo Craft 3 training course.       ``{% if entry.programImageCaption %}
            <p class="caption">
                <small>{{ entry.programImageCaption }}</small>
            </p>
            {% endif %}.``

Comment: @Hellyar Yes but this was an example for a string, currently you don't have a string but an object. You need to know what type of variables you use

Comment: I have both solutions up an running now. I did not think of the `string` vs. `object` angle.  I wrongly assumed if it worked for one field it would work for the other.  I have both solutions up and running now.  Thanks.

Comment: Every field returns a different variable. Many people tend to assume they only receive strings or an array of elements in Craft fields but most of them return something else. They just have a `__toString()` function in order to display the mostly assumed data when you do `entry.fieldHandle` that's the way how Redactor fields work

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem a couple of days ago (Craft newbie). I wanted to make it obvious that the image was missing, so I uploaded an image asset for the "No image" case. Then in the template, I used this for the src attribute on the image tag:

```
{{(entry.programImage.one() ?? craft.assets.id(47).one()).getUrl()}}
```

It's using the null coalescing operator **??**, so if entry.programImage.one() is *not* **null**, it gets returned and if it *is* **null** it loads a specific image asset (my 'no image' picture, represented by id 47). Then it does a getUrl on which ever image is selected.